# Send Json Data Between activities with ArrayList

Tags: android, json

i'm setting data from Json Object to MyData Class and add to `ArrayList` and want to send this `ArrayList` to another `Activity` to show data on `RecyclerView`.

i tried With `parcelable` and it doesn't work for me.

```
public class MyData implements Parcelable {

    private String name,password;

    public MyData() {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = password;
    }
 public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

protected MyData(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    password = in.readString();
}

public static final Creator<MyData> CREATOR = new Creator<MyData>() {
    @Override
    public MyData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new MyData(in);
    }

    @Override
    public MyData[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyData[size];
    }
};



@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeString(password);
}
```

}

this part of Mydata Calss with Getter and setter

```
class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<MyData> myData;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<MyData> myData) {
    this.context = context;
    this.myData = myData;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_inflater, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.name.setText(myData.get(position).getName());
    holder.pass.setText(myData.get(position).getPassword());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return myData.size();
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView name,pass;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
        pass = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pass_txt);
    }
}
```

}
// My Adapter Plz Hlep

MainActivity1

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    data_list = new ArrayList<>();




}



public void GoOnClick(View view) {

    load_from_data();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , Main2Activity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("key", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) data_list);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);


}



 private void load_from_data() 
{

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, get_info_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {

                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("users");

                    for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject users = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        MyData myData = new MyData();

                        myData.setName(users.getString("name"));
                        myData.setPassword(users.getString("password"));

                        data_list.add(myData);

                    }



                } catch (Exception e) {}



            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        //setrecyclerview(data_list);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }
```

//method for get Data form Json Object

MainActivity2

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    mainList = new ArrayList<>();
    mainList = this.getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("key");
    setrecyclerview(mainList);

}

private void setrecyclerview(List<MyData> data_list) {

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, data_list);
    DividerItemDecoration divider = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), new LinearLayoutManager(this).getOrientation());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(divider);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

// set Data on Recycler View But Doesn't Work :(

06-07 17:04:30.190 6255-6255/com.example.bat.ivolleyrecycler E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bat.ivolleyrecycler, PID: 6255
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
        at com.example.bat.ivolleyrecycler.MainActivity.GoOnClick(MainActivity.java:55)

// Errore

i expect when Click On Button in MainActivity1 Show me Data on Recycler View On MainActivity2

Comment: Post MyData whole class. At least in the portion of code you shared, the parcelable implementation is incomplete (writeToParcel, constructor with parcel, CREATOR methods are missing...)

Comment: as you wish here All Code :((

Comment: Thanks for the code. I do not see anything wrong in the parcelable implementation. The error message suggests that the onClick method can not be executed so my impression is that there is something wrong with your button, not the code executed by the onClick. How do you define and declare this button?

Comment: very simple add onClik in xml and mainAcrity and set Load_data method on it

Comment: You could post the xml code to see if anything is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
ArrayList<MyData> list = new ArrayList<MyData>();
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable("myList",(Serializable)list);
intent.putExtra("myKey",args);
startActivity(intent);
```

And get the arraylist into your `MainActivity.java` Like:

```
Bundle args = getIntent().getBundleExtra("myKey");
ArrayList<MyData> newList = (ArrayList<MyData>) args.getSerializable("myList");
```

Comment: compiler Error to my adapter about Object ArrayList see ,my Adapter plz

Comment: I think your adapter is ok.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bat.ivolleyrecycler, PID: 6255

Answer (score 0):

```
Gson gson = new Gson;

    //this code to send data via intent

        String json = new Gson().toJson(yourList);

     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this , Main2Activity.class);
     intent.putExtra("key",json);

        startActivity(intent);


    //this code to get data from intent
    mainList = new ArrayList<>();
 mainList = gson.fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("key"), new TypeToken<List<MyData>>() {
        }.getType());
```

Comment: TypeToken deprecated:|

Answer (score 0):

You can create model of your JSON data in jsonpojo online and to redesign your model class again. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/.then it would work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("A", ArrayList.);
                context.startActivity(intent);
```

in next activity

```
if(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("A") != null){ list = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("A");}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

instead of putParcelableArrayList use putExtra and instead of getParcelableArrayList use getParcelableExtra.

pass data:

```
intent.putExtra(key, list)
```

get data:

```
list=getIntent().getParcelableExtra(key)
```